# How to create Handlebars.js library of reusable partials?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'd like to create a library of UI objects in Handlebars.js that I can use in multiple projects. Something like this:

```
{{#partial foo}}
  my foo template
{{/partial}}
{{#partial bar}}
  my bar template
{{/partial}}
```

I'd then just include this file in my project and insert the partials into my templates as needed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

http://assemble.io has lots of great examples, and is a great tool for creating, mocking, and maintaining libraries of partials.

If you'd like to see an example in practice, Assemble's docs use a small collection of partials, [found here](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-docs/tree/master/src/templates/includes).